# OO Design Issue related to subclassing

Tags: oop

I have a parent bean having one instance variable like below :

```java
public Class ParentBean {
    protected boolean show; // this variable will be used to show some UI component 

    public void action() {                  
        // update show variable here 
    }

    public boolean isShow() {       
        return show;
    }    
}
```

Is it a good design if I want to reuse the "show" variable in a child bean (to show other UI component specific to child bean ) as shown below :

```java
public Class ChildBean extends ParentBean {
    // override the action method from parent bean 
    public void action() {                      
        // update show variable here 
        show = true /false;
    }           
}
```

In effect , show variable is being updated by "childBean" by overriding action() method.
Is this a good design practice ? Otherwise same thing has to be repeated in ChildBean to get this work done.

Comment: I this this is absolutely fine. The derived implementations can modify the state of the base class object, if it is permitted by the base class.

Comment: @Atul please remember marking your questions as answered (or if you don't think that's a good answer just discuss it). That's a reward for best answer's author. I mention that because I [once answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14788100/1199132) you without reply.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: yes , i am really sorry for that and it shouldn't have happened but i am yet to look into the answer and will definitely going to comment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `show` variable for the same purpose in the subclass, as you seem to be doing in this example, then obviously you should reuse it, because otherwise you just end up writing the same code twice, which is contrary to the point of OOP.

In general, in OOP, it is common to override superclass methods in subclasses, as well as modifying superclass instance variables, **as long as you know what the variable you are modifying is being used for** (you don't want to be randomly changing instance variables in classes that you don't completely understand, or don't have access to the source of, because you don't want any unfortunate side effects), so when it's your own code, this is absolutely fine.

As a general guideline, if your options are either to copy and paste a massive hunk of code and use it unchanged, or subclass and use the superclass' instance variables or functions, it's better to subclass. Otherwise, you're missing out on the point of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

It is. Having a `protected` variable means you are allowed to modify it into parent or children classes (remember every **single instance** of each class has **its own property values**). So, if you have some generic functionality which is valuable for all the children:

**Parent class:**

```java
public void action(){
    //update show variable here 
    show = true;
}
```

Appart from that, if you want to add some extra functionality in a specifical child:

**Child class:**

```java
@Override
public void action(){
    super.action();
    //Extra functionality goes here 
    //You can also access parent's 'protected' fields
    if (show){
        System.out.println("Shown");
    }
}
```

**An example of the use:**

```java
Parent p = new Parent();
p.action();//Prints nothing

Child c = new Child();
p.action();//Prints 'shown'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the value in subclass will not affect superclass variable**

This is fine with respect to the design. When a subclass object is instantiated, it will have a different copy of variable. and If superclass object is instantiated it will have different copy.